# Unclear about what to pass through a given Action<T,R>

Tags: c#, .net-core, restsharp

I am attempting to implement the library `RestSharp.Core` in a `.NET Core` application; But it has no documentation.

I need to implement this method;

```
public virtual RestRequestAsyncHandle ExecuteAsyncPost(IRestRequest request, Action<IRestResponse, RestRequestAsyncHandle> callback, string httpMethod)
```

I cannot figure out what to pass for the second parameter. This is the code I was using in normal `RestSharp` before I had to start converting it to .NET Core.

```
var httpResponse = await httpClient.ExecutePostTaskAsync(httpRequest);
var deserializer = new RestSharp.Deserializers.JsonDeserializer();
return deserializer.Deserialize<Dictionary<string, string>>(httpResponse);
```

Any ideas? I'm really confused.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

RestSharp uses a callback-style kind of asynchrony which is very common in other platforms (e.g., Node), but never really caught on in .NET.

In order to *implement* `ExecuteAsyncPost`, you will need to take the `request` and `httpMethod` parameters to start an asynchronous post and then return a `RestRequestAsyncHandle` representing that operation.

Then, when the post completes, you should build an `IRestResponse` instance and pass that along with the `RestRequestAsyncHandle` to the `callback`. The `RestRequestAsyncHandle` you pass to `callback` should be the same instance as the one you already returned from `ExecuteAsyncPost`.

Since `RestRequestAsyncHandle` appears to be built around `HttpWebRequest`, you should be able to do something like:

```
public override RestRequestAsyncHandle ExecuteAsyncPost(IRestRequest request, Action<IRestResponse, RestRequestAsyncHandle> callback, string httpMethod)
{
  HttpWebRequest webRequest = /* Construct webRequest from request/httpMethod */
  var result = new RestRequestAsyncHandle(webRequest);
  DoWebRequest(webRequest, result, callback);
}

private async void DoWebRequest(HttpWebRequest webRequest, RestRequestAsyncHandle result, Action<IRestResponse, RestRequestAsyncHandle> callback)
{
  IRestResponse response;
  try
  {
    var webResponse = await webRequest.GetResponseAsync().ConfigureAwait(false);
    response = /* Construct an IRestResponse using webResponse */
  }
  catch (Exception ex)
  {
    response = /* Construct an IRestResponse with error information */
  }
  callback(response, result);
}
```

Note that I'm purposely using `async void` here because we're implementing a callback-based asynchronous system, and I *want* exceptions from the callback method to be handled at a top level. In the vast majority of normal `async`/`await` usage, you should *avoid* `async void`.

Comment: Thank you so much, this really helped.

Answer (score 0):

The second parameter is an `Action` (method) that takes a `RestRequestAsyncHandle` and returns a `IRestResponse`.

In other words, this method is looking for a method to call as a call back when it's done.

Comment: Right, I understand that. But I'm having a hard time figuring out what that method should look like. I though `(request, handler) => { }` would work, but it doesn't.

Comment: Wait... You say it takes one and returns the other. That might make a bit more sense..

Comment: Yes, your method has to return something. Your lambda takes both and returns void. It's not going to compile.